# whitespaces and returns on query string variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it ok to have whitespaces and returns in a query string? I want my code to look pretty and readable, but the side-effect of that is whitespaces. Is there anything wrong with setting up my query string like below? Does it affect performance in any way?

```
// set-up query string
$sql = "    SELECT some_column, another_column
            FROM my_table
            WHERE id = 15";

// prepare statement..
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($sql))
{
    exit;
}

// bind params, execute, blah blah blah..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB (or any other) performance is not going to be affected in any way. Feel free to indent and format your queries as much as you like. The developers who will work with your code later will thank you deeply for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would like to say that the queries what u write they must be such that they are maximally readable.
to make minimal load on server, you can use option to remove the white space which good habit of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with having whitespaces in both PHP and HTML, unless you are echoing PHP strings.

An easy way to confirm that is to try putting a lot of spaces between `<h1></h1>` tags, only 1 whitespaces will be outputed.

Thus, usually whitespaces does not matter. Having whitespaces can make your code neater and easier to diagnose for problems.